# Error while parsing yaml in golang

Tags: go, struct, yaml

I’ve a yaml like following which I need to parse using go. 
When I tried to run the code with the parse I got an error.
Below is the code:

```
var runContent= []byte(`

- runners:
   - name: function1
     type: func1
      - command: spawn child process
      - command: build
      - command: gulp

  - name: function1
    type: func2
      - command: run function 1
  - name: function3
    type: func3
      - command: ruby build

  - name: function4
    type: func4
      - command: go build 

`)
```

These are the types:

```
type Runners struct {

    runners string `yaml:"runners"`
        name string `yaml:”name”`
        Type: string  `yaml: ”type”`
        command  [] Command 
}


type Command struct {
    command string `yaml: ”command”`
}



runners := Runners{}
err = yaml.Unmarshal(runContent, &runners)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error : %v", err)
}
```

When I try to parse it I got an error `invalid map` , what could be missing here ?

Comment: In Go you have to export all struct fields subject to marshaling / unmarshaling!

Comment: Also your struct doesn't look good from here in terms of spec.

Comment: The indentation in the YAML document is incorrect, and it doesn't match the Go types. `type` can be either a string, a list, or a map. Pick one. You are also mixing ASCII and unicode quotes in your struct tags. Use ASCII only.

Comment: You have some "smart quotes" e.g. here: `yaml:”name”`. If those are in your actual code (rather than just a copy/paste mishap in this StackOverflow snippet), then that would give you trouble of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted contains multiple errors including the struct field `Type`. The yaml provided in your code is not valid. This will lead to err when unmarshalling the yaml into struct.

On unmarshalling yaml in go, It is required that:

> The type of the decoded values should be compatible with the
>   respective values in out. If one or more values cannot be decoded due
>   to a type mismatches, decoding continues partially until the end of
>   the YAML content, and a *yaml.TypeError is returned with details for
>   all missed values.

Along with that:

> Struct fields are only unmarshalled if they are exported (have an
>   upper case first letter), and are unmarshalled using the field name
>   lowercased as the default key.

Also there is an error in defining the `yaml` tags, which contains space. Custom keys may be defined via the "yaml" name in the field tag: the content preceding the first comma is used as the key.

```
type Runners struct {

    runners string `yaml:"runners"` // fields should be exportable
        name string `yaml:”name”`
        Type: string  `yaml: ”type”` // tags name should not have space in them.
        command  [] Command 
}
```

To make the struct exportable convert the struct and fields into uppercase starting letter and remove space in yaml tag names:

```
type Runners struct {
    Runners string `yaml:"runners"`
    Name string `yaml:"name"`
    Type string `yaml:"type"`
    Command  []Command 
}

type Command struct {
    Command string `yaml:"command"`
}
```

Modify the code as below to make it work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var runContent = []byte(`
- runners:
  - name: function1
    type:
    - command: spawn child process
    - command: build
    - command: gulp
  - name: function1
    type:
    - command: run function 1
  - name: function3
    type:
    - command: ruby build
  - name: function4
    type:
    - command: go build
`)

type Runners []struct {
    Runners []struct {
        Type []struct {
            Command string `yaml:"command"`
        } `yaml:"type"`
        Name string `yaml:"name"`
    } `yaml:"runners"`
}

func main() {

    runners := Runners{}
    // parse mta yaml
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(runContent, &runners)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error : %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(runners)
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/bSZotdTjPJY)

Validate your yaml online here https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/cb92c85b

Comment: THANKS, in your example you use json, why ?

Comment: @RaynD no I have used provided yaml just change the format to validate the same.

Comment: @RaynD just use the code that I have written and compare it with yours to check what is wrong with your code. My one is working and it is using yaml. Just I have validated the yaml first which was wrong in your code.

Comment: Thanks, when I check it like this, it's not working , why ? (I used the structure you suggested ) https://play.golang.org/p/nHGui7xZG7V

Comment: the error is: `cannot unmarshal !!seq into main.Runners`

Comment: @RaynD have you verified the yaml provided in the code in the link at last

Comment: @RaynD try this link which contains a nested struct. https://play.golang.org/p/VqLTE3BIkBW. It is working code.

Comment: This is what I used in the example playgorund https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/cb92c85b

Comment: yes you used json, why this is not working play.golang.org/p/nHGui7xZG7V  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178245/discussion-between-himanshu-and-rayn-d).

Comment: See also this , if you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907530/parse-yaml-error , thanks!