# Parse yaml error for map

Tags: go, struct, yaml

I've the following program in which I need to parse yaml
with the following structure

https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/cbabd352
this is **valid yaml** and I use byte to make it more simple 
maybe the indentation was changed during the copy paste to the question but you can see in the link that the yaml is valid

The yaml have an api_version 
and runners, for each runner (key which is name) I've a list of commands
and I need to print those commands for `function1` and `function4` ,what am I doing wrong here ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var runContent = []byte(`
api_ver: 1
runners:
 - name: function1
   type:
    - command: spawn child process
    - command: build
    - command: gulp
 - name: function2
   type:
    - command: run function 1
 - name: function3
   type:
    - command: ruby build
 - name: function4
   type:
    - command: go build
`)

type Result struct {
    Version string    `yaml:"api_ver"`
    Runners []Runners `yaml:"runners"`
}

type Runners struct {
    Name string    `yaml:"name"`
    Type []Command `yaml:"type"`
}

type Command struct {
    Command string `yaml:"command"`
}

func main() {

    var runners []Result
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(runContent, &runners)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error : %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", runners[0])
}
```

The error which I got `cannot unmarshal !!map into []main.Result`

I cannot change the yaml and it should be exactly like this

https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/cbabd352

This is the code
https://play.golang.org/p/zidjOA6-gc7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yaml that you have provided contains error in token. Validate the yaml used in your code here https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/cbaabb32

After that Create a variable of struct type result not an array. Because the yaml that you are using is creating a struct  with Runners array and api_version.

This

```
var runners []Result
```

should be

```
var runners Result
```

Since because the struct is not a slice. To fetch the list of command for a name of function used in yaml. You need to loop over the runners array to find the name of function and get the value of commands for that function.
Below is the working code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var runContent = []byte(`
api_ver: 1
runners:
  - name: function1
    type:
    - command: spawn child process
    - command: build
    - command: gulp
  - name: function2
    type:
    - command: run function 1
    - name: function3
    type:
    - command: ruby build
  - name: function4
    type:
  - command: go build
`)

type Result struct {
    Version string    `yaml:"api_ver"`
    Runners []Runners `yaml:"runners"`
}

type Runners struct {
    Name string    `yaml:"name"`
    Type []Command `yaml:"type"`
}

type Command struct {
    Command string `yaml:"command"`
}

func main() {

    var runners Result
    // parse mta yaml
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(runContent, &runners)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error : %v", err)
    }
    commandList := getCommandList("function1", runners.Runners)
    fmt.Printf("%+v", commandList)
}

func getCommandList(name string, runners []Runners) []Command {
    var commandList []Command
    for _, value := range runners {
        if value.Name == name {
            commandList = value.Type
        }
    }
    return commandList
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/G8FdTAF9Pke)

Comment: Thanks 1 . what is the diffrent from my question ?   2.  lets say I have function which get as parameter the name for the runner and print the commands of it , how can we  do it ?

Comment: 1+ ok so you explain it on the question :)  can you please provide example to my second question ?

Comment: @RaynD because you are using tabs for spaces in yaml. So you should avoid tabs when creating a yaml. Also I have given the link where you can check if your yaml is valid. Always check if your yaml is valid before unmarshaling.

Comment: the yaml was ok :), `var runners Result` this is the diffrance

Comment: and regard my second question, can you please provide example `"lets say I have function which get as parameter the name for the runner and print the commands of it , how can we do it ? "`

Comment: @RaynD yes you just need to create a function which will return the slice of commands on basis of function

Comment: Can you please provide example in your answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178249/discussion-between-himanshu-and-rayn-d).

Comment: please see if you can assist here , it is similar but diffrent :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948670/match-array-according-to-value

Comment: @RaynD I have added  a link to playground for full example for new question you have asked. you can check it from there also.