# Match array according to value

Tags: go, struct, yaml, slice

I'm using the following code to parse yaml and should get output as `runners` object and the function `build`should change the data structure and provide output according to below struct

```
type Exec struct {
    NameVal string
    Executer []string
}
```

This is what I have tried but I'm not sure how to **replace 
the hard-code values** inside the function runner from the value I'm getting inside the yaml

```
return []Exec{
    {"#mytest",
        []string{"spawn child process", "build", "gulp"}},
}
```

with the data from the `parsed runner`

This is all what I have tried any idea how it could be done?

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var runContent = []byte(`
api_ver: 1
runners:
  - name: function1
    data: mytest
    type:
    - command: spawn child process
    - command: build
    - command: gulp
  - name: function2
    data: mytest2
    type:
    - command: webpack
  - name: function3
    data: mytest3
    type:
    - command: ruby build
  - name: function4
    type:
  - command: go build
`)

type Result struct {
    Version string    `yaml:"api_ver"`
    Runners []Runners `yaml:"runners"`
}

type Runners struct {
    Name string    `yaml:"name"`
    Type []Command `yaml:"type"`
}

type Command struct {
    Command string `yaml:"command"`
}

func main() {

    var runners Result
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(runContent, &runners)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error : %v", err)
    }

    //Here Im calling to the function with the parsed structured data  which need to return the list of Exec
    build("function1", runners)

}

type Exec struct {
    NameVal  string
    Executer []string
}

func build(name string, runners Result) []Exec {

    for _, runner := range runners.Runners {

        if name == runner.Name {
            return []Exec{
                // this just for example, nameVal and Command
                {"# mytest",
                    []string{"spawn child process", "build", "gulp"}},
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the name of runners object to the struct `Exec` field for name and append the command list to the `[]string` type field with the commands of the function that matched the name as:

```
func build(name string, runners Result) []Exec {
    exec := make([]Exec, len(runners.Runners))
    for i, runner := range runners.Runners {

        if name == runner.Name {
            exec[i].NameVal = runner.Name
            for _, cmd := range runner.Type {
                exec[i].Executer = append(exec[i].Executer, cmd.Command)
            }
            fmt.Printf("%+v", exec)
            return exec
        }
    }
    return exec
}
```

Working code on [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LDs0RMppkAA)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to return `Exec`, can you please update?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, as my question I need to return []Exec

Comment: @RaynD Edited my answer just check the new build function. For full example check the Playground link